# Function return decimal type without decimal poin and zeros

Tags: postgresql

I have table with column type `decimal(12,2)`. When I using select from this table all work
fine, select return values like

```
0.00
1.23
1.00
2.00
3.33
```

But when I create functions

```
create or replace function t.tst()
returns table (comm decimal(12,2))
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    return query
    select t.comm from pay.test t;
end;
$$
```

And call this function, they return values like this:

```
0
1.23
1
2
3.33
```

Without decimal points and zeros, how to fix this?

Comment: Works for me, the function does not need fixing. To your question add 1) Postgres version. 2) How you call the function 3) What client you are using the function in.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function test()
returns table (comm decimal(12,2))
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    return query
    select t.test::decimal(12,2) from pay t;
end;
$$;
```

output

```
select * from test();
 comm
------
 0.00
 1.23
 1.00
 2.00
 3.33
```

Comment: this is not work

Comment: everything should work fine here is the [link](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/60e2636)